# How to import-csv and concatenate with prefix and suffix

Tags: powershell

my csv file:

```
SamAccountName,Description

sarah1,sales
peter2,sales
```

I need to modify the samaccountname with a prefix and suffix of *sarah1* in order to then search AD for all samaccountnames with the word sarah1.
*because sarah1 has multiple accounts ie: -admin-sarah1-us and -admin-sarah1-uk

Noob status goes without saying :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can concatenate strings like this:

```
 $string = "prefix" + $user.SamAccountName + "suffix"
```

but if you want to get all accounts for e.g. sarah1 i suggest you use a filter with wildcards.

Here is an example for `Get-ADUser`:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -like '*$($user.SamAccountName)*'"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your CSV file also includes user names other than sarah so I assume you'll be polling AD for multiple users with many accounts. Each query to AD could take  a long time depending on the size of the directory. If this is the case and you should consider creating a staging csv file with an export of the attributes you need from AD.
 
The `CSVDE` utility on your Domain Controller can help with that, use the `-l` switch to specify which attributes you are interested in.
Then do something like

> $file = import-csv yourinput.csv 
>   $ADAttributes = import-csv outputfromcsvde.csv 
>   foreach ($line in $file)  { $ADAttributes | ? {$_.samAcountName -match $line.samAccountName}